# Can Scipy's minimum function optimize the value of a class data member?

Tags: python, class, optimization, scipy, neural-network

I'm working on a [ANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), and got it working on simple AND/XOR problems using gradient descent, but I am finding it much more difficult to find the optimal weights for more complex problems. My solution was to use Scipy's minimum function instead, but I am having some trouble.

My ANN is a class, and when ANN object is created, weights are created upon initialization as the data member self.__weights, this is useful because I don't actually have to pass a weights parameter into any of the methods used on the class, and it worked in my earlier non-Scipy using implementation.

I use the self.__weights as the initial guess for the minimum function, and pass in the other arguments(input data, the correct output values) needed to make the function work. But it seems, that the optimizer keeps passing the weights into the methods(Cost Function/FeedForward/Backprop) as a parameter when there is no need to since it can be called with self.__weights. For instance, when my FeedForward method is called, it passes in the weights, and states that the input isn't of the correct size, this is because the weights were passed in instead. And the input data is passed into the minimum's optional 'arg=' parameter.

So, all explanation done, must the value to be optimized actually be a parameter of the methods being used to optimized it, and not just a class data member that can be called from anywhere within in the class? I've tried to find examples using a class they pass in there 'weights' or other value to be optimized depending on there use, not a data member of the class.

EDIT:

This is code a snippet is located in my train method. It's parameters are `input_data` and `target`.

```
opt_theta = minimize(self.CostFunction,x0=self.__weights,args = (input_data,target),method='Newton-CG',jac= self.Weight_Grad)       
    print(opt_theta)
    self.__weights = opt_theta.x
```

`self.CostFunction` and `self.Weight_Grad` both take those same two parameters. Both of these latter two functions use a Feedforward method to get the output of the network, and do there respective task with that info. Whenever I call the minimize function it seems it passes `self.__weights` into `self.CostFunction` as the `input_data` parameter, which then gets passed into the FeedForward method as input and I get an error. IF i print the "input" passed into Feedforward it is the value of `self.__weights`. This is how I know `self.__weights` is getting passed in as a parameter when it shouldn't.

So, I thought I would create a "dummy"? parameter to pass the the `self.__weights` value into for all of the methods('self.CostFunction`,'self.Weight_Grad`,`Feedforward`) and an error did not occur but there was no change in the weights or the output. What do I need to do to get self.__weights to update.

Here are the methods in case it helps:

```
def Feedforward(self,input):

        #Code to take self.__weights and convert to list of matrices. 
        weight_matrix_list = []
        prev_val = 0


        for i in range(len(self.__weight_sizes)):
            curr_w_size = self.__weight_sizes[i]
            weight_count = curr_w_size[0]*curr_w_size[1]
            matrix_elements = self.__weights[prev_val:prev_val+weight_count]
            weight_matrix_list.append(matrix_elements.reshape(curr_w_size))


        self.__input_cases = np.shape(input)[0]

        #Empty list to hold the output of every layer.
        output_list = []
        #Appends the output of the the 1st input layer.
        output_list.append(input)

        for i in range(self.__layers-1):
            if i == 0:

                print(self.__input_cases)
                print(input)
                X = np.concatenate((np.ones((self.__input_cases,1)),input),1)

                output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(X,weight_matrix_list[0].T))
                output_list.append(output)
            else:
                output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(np.concatenate((np.ones((self.__input_cases,1)),output),1),weight_matrix_list[i].T))                 
                output_list.append(output)


        return output_list

    def CostFunction(self,input_data,target,error_func=1):
        """Gives the cost of using a particular weight matrix 
        based off of the input and targeted output"""
        print("Cost")
        #Run the network to get output using current theta matrices.
        output = self.Feedforward(input_data)[-1]


        #Determines number of input/training examples
        m = np.shape(input_data)[0]

        #####Allows user to choose Cost Functions.##### 

        #
        #Log Based Error Function
        #
        if error_func == 0:
            error = np.multiply(-target,np.log(output))-np.multiply((1-target),np.log(1-output))
            total_error = np.sum(np.sum(error))
        #    
        #Squared Error Cost Function
        #
        elif error_func == 1:
            error = (target - output)**2
            total_error = (1/(2*m)) * np.sum(np.sum(error))

        return total_error

    def Weight_Grad(self,input_data,target):
        print('Grad')
        weight_matrix_list = []
        prev_val = 0

        for i in range(len(self.__weight_sizes)):
            curr_w_size = self.__weight_sizes[i]
            weight_count = curr_w_size[0]*curr_w_size[1]
            matrix_elements = self.__weights[prev_val:prev_val+weight_count]
            weight_matrix_list.append(matrix_elements.reshape(curr_w_size))        

        output_list = self.Feedforward(theta,input_data)

        #Finds the Deltas for Each Layer
        # 
        deltas = []
        for i in range(self.__layers - 1):
            #Finds Error Delta for the last layer
            if i == 0:

                error = (target-output_list[-1])

                error_delta = -1*np.multiply(error,np.multiply(output_list[-1],(1-output_list[-1])))
                deltas.append(error_delta)
            #Finds Error Delta for the hidden layers   
            else:
                #Weight matrices have bias values removed
                error_delta = np.multiply(np.dot(deltas[-1],weight_matrix_list[-i][:,1:]),output_list[-i-1]*(1-output_list[-i-1]))
                deltas.append(error_delta)

        #
        #Finds the Deltas for each Weight Matrix
        #
        Weight_Delta_List = []
        deltas.reverse()
        for i in range(len(weight_matrix_list)):

            current_weight_delta = (1/self.__input_cases) * np.dot(deltas[i].T,np.concatenate((np.ones((self.__input_cases,1)),output_list[i]),1))
            Weight_Delta_List.append(current_weight_delta)




        #
        #Converts Weight Delta List to a single vector
        #        
        Weight_Delta_Vector = np.array([])
        for i in range(len(Weight_Delta_List)):
            Weight_Delta_Vector = np.concatenate((Weight_Delta_Vector,Weight_Delta_List[i].flatten()))
        print("WDV Shape:",np.shape(Weight_Delta_Vector))
        return Weight_Delta_Vector

    def Train(self,input_data,target):           

        opt_theta = minimize(self.CostFunction,x0=self.__weights,args = (input_data,target),method='Newton-CG',jac= self.Weight_Grad)       
        print(opt_theta)
        self.__weights = opt_theta.x

        print("Done")
```

Comment: Show us some minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added some code and went into greater detail.